# can I integrate product or square of a white noise in any sense?

Tags: stochastic-calculus, schwartz-distributions, wiener-measure

Assume that we have $\epsilon_1, \; \epsilon_2$ independent white noises.

1. Can I write $\int_{0}^1 \epsilon_1^2(t)dt$
2. Can I write $\int_{0}^1 \epsilon_1(t) \epsilon_2(t)dt$

1 and 2 obviously make no sense in $L^2$ nor in terms of Wiener integral. Is there any way I can make sense out of it?

Comment: The answer provided by Carlo Beenakker was very helpful. However the articles provided do not cover the case of white noise multiplication - only powers. Does anyone have any clue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A consistent framework for "nonlinear stochastic calculus" has been developed in [The square of white noise as a Jacobi field](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0401370v1) (2004), building on earlier work in [Squared white noise and other non-Gaussian noises as Lévy processes on real Lie algebras](https://art.torvergata.it/retrieve/handle/2108/75107/147446/AcFrSk00.pdf) (2002). A more pedestrian approach (perhaps more suited to your purpose) is taken in [On powers of Gaussian white noise](http://arxiv.org/abs/1010.2992) (2010), and [Spectra for the product of Gaussian noises](http://arxiv.org/abs/1207.1881) (2012).

Comment: Is there a place to read an introductory and simple information White Noise? Specifically about its Auto Correlation Function?